# Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable

Tags: react-native, io, cocoapods

Running into an issue and error when I go to run the mobile app. I think it has something to do with the cocoapods but I'm not sure. Can someone help me or give me a call?

Im building out the App.js file and creating a drawer navigation currently.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what worked was:

1. restarting the javascript bundler

```
   1. Ctrl + c
   2. npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

2. restarting my emulator or simulator device

```
   1. npx react-native run-android
```